# Schunk_lwa4p initialization error with ros_canopen

Tags: ros, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to run the schunk lwa4p arm with ros_canopen package but was not able to initialize the robot. The nodes are running and the can is set up but the rosservice call /arm/driver/init was not able to initialize the robot. I am attaching the candump output of the service along with other outputs.

I am using the shunck_lwa4p package from schunk_robots.

Please find the link to the gist with respective files https://gist.github.com/rishabhagarwal880/9bb9aa3b25dadad3d81a66ce97c59ca6

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266252/schunk_lwa4p-initialization-error-with-ros_canopen/) by [Rishabh](https://answers.ros.org/users/25857/rishabh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-07-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2017-07-13**:
Which firmware version do you use?

**Comment by [Rishabh](https://answers.ros.org/users/25857/rishabh/) on 2017-07-14**:
I am using ubuntu 14.04 as a docker on fedora 25 with ros indigo.

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2017-07-14**:
I really meant the Schunk firmware version, the config in `schunk_robots` works for v0.63 only.
(With some modification it might work with v0.65, we don't use it)

**Comment by [Rishabh](https://answers.ros.org/users/25857/rishabh/) on 2017-07-14**:
The canalyzer shows the manufacturer software version as 65 Build:7589. I am not sure if that is the correct version for the configuration file we have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For v0.65 please try to set an initial operation mode, this worked for me in a beta version:

Add `ParameterValue=1` to the [DCF](https://github.com/ipa320/schunk_robots/blob/indigo_dev/schunk_lwa4p/config/Schunk_0_63.dcf#L1242).

As an alternative you can add `"6060": "1"` to  [dcf_overlay](https://github.com/ipa320/schunk_robots/blob/indigo_dev/schunk_lwa4p/config/arm_driver.yaml#L9).

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2017-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rishabh](https://answers.ros.org/users/25857/rishabh/) on 2017-07-14**:
The robot was initialized after I made the suggested changes. Thank you for the help.

**Comment by [Rishabh](https://answers.ros.org/users/25857/rishabh/) on 2017-07-14**:
Although the robot initializes successfully, I am still not able to control the robot using the position controllers. I am spawning the controllers using the ros_control package and they are spawing successfully.

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2017-07-14**:
Check the diagnostics for hints,.

**Comment by [Rishabh](https://answers.ros.org/users/25857/rishabh/) on 2017-07-14**:
The drives are in the Profile position mode but I think to control the robot with the position controller I need to bring them in interpolated position mode. I will take a more detailed look at the diagnostics too.

**Comment by [k5519995](https://answers.ros.org/users/40605/k5519995/) on 2019-04-27**:
What to do for v0.67 ?

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2019-04-30**:
I guess the same(?)

**Comment by [k5519995](https://answers.ros.org/users/40605/k5519995/) on 2019-06-06**:
Yes. It's working